# Do deleted comments exist anywhere?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

Do deleted comments exist anywhere?

My recent question about [Trump's January 6 speech](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61748/how-did-trumps-january-6-speech-call-for-insurrection-and-violence/61765?noredirect=1#comment245461_61765) had this comment:

> If I am sitting by a deep swimming pool and see an unsupervised toddler child playing close to the edge - and then watch the child fall in and drown, and do absolutely nothing to prevent it - I am, certainly under English law, guilty of a crime.

I was about to reply to it, but the comment is no longer there, and I don't remember who made it.

Answer (score 6):

[Not for normal users.  Moderators can see them, however.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187281/165261)

One small exception would be that if the comment was posted, but not deleted, [before the previous Sunday at around 03:00 UTC](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq), it would be able to be queried via the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), which receives a snapshot of the network's current state at that time.